# How can i get the "line number" that have certain string in a txt file?

Tags: python

blues.txt

> aaaaaaaaaa
>   bbbbbbbbbb
>   tango:55
>   dddddddddd

I want to make this to

> aaaaaaaaaa
>   bbbbbbbbbb
>   tango:5500
>   dddddddddd

My Python book don't have information how to do this.

```
f = open("blues.txt", 'r', encoding = 'utf')

jool = f.readlines()

find("tango")
line(find)
```

Comment: is your goal to find the line with the word tango then append '00' to the line?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by the following:

```
with open('blues.txt','r') as f:
    with open('out.txt','w') as out:
        for line in f:
            if 'tango' in line:
                out.write(line.replace('\n','00\n'))
            else:
                out.write(line)
```

output:

```
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
tango:5500
dddddddddd
```

while going through the lines, just do an if statement to handle your desired operation if the line includes the word 'tango'

EDIT if your want the line number (starting at 1), do this:

```
count=1
with open('blues.txt','r') as f:
    with open('out.txt','w') as out:
        for line in f:
            if 'tango' in line:
                out.write(line.replace('\n','00\n'))
                print('changed line '+str(count))
            else:
                out.write(line)
            count+=1
```

output:

```
changed line 3
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. Bless you.

Comment: not a problem..best of luck in your pythonic adventures

Comment: It works perfect, but how can i know that "changed line's" number?
like aaa...=1 bbb...=2 and at tango...= "3"

Comment: added an edit, using this method (there are other ways) you can just initialize a counter

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is detect a substring in the line, then add the 00 and use .join:

```py
f = open("blues.txt", "r", encoding = "utf")

lines = f.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if lines[i].find("tango") != -1:
        lines[i]+="00"
f.close
f = open("blues.txt", "w", encoding = "utf")
f.write(lines.join("\n"))
```

Comment: sorry Derek Eden, I was writing this while you posted you answer.

Comment: I got this message, 
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'open'

Comment: I had accidentally put .open instead of = open, the code should work now